# Reading from a text file not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, text-files

For my code there are 3 list collections. One that holds Employees(with parameters of Name/ID) and service requests(that holds parameters name/id/description). Then the third is Assignments that holds an employee and service request from the other 2 lists (assigning an employee to a service request).

I have reading working for the employees/service requests but for assignments im getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  when i run my code, and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

The error points at `assignment.Employee.Name = columns[0];` I was thinking it might be something like `//assignment.Employee = columns[0];` to assign the whole employee object to column[0]. But then it gives the error that I can't convert string to MaintenanceManagementSystem.Employee.

/Code for reading employees.

```
    public static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        StreamReader textIn =
            new StreamReader(
                new FileStream(path1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string row = textIn.ReadLine();
            string[] columns = row.Split('|');
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.Name = columns[0];
            employee.ID = columns[1];
            employees.Add(employee);
        }

        textIn.Close();

        return employees;
    }
```

/ Code for reading requests

```
    public static List<ServiceRequest> GetRequest()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        StreamReader textIn =
            new StreamReader(
                new FileStream(path2, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

        List<ServiceRequest> serviceRequests = new List<ServiceRequest>();

        while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string row = textIn.ReadLine();
            string[] columns = row.Split('|');
            ServiceRequest serviceRequest = new ServiceRequest();
            serviceRequest.Name = columns[0];
            serviceRequest.ID = columns[1];
            serviceRequest.Desc = columns[2];
            serviceRequests.Add(serviceRequest);
        }

        textIn.Close();

        return serviceRequests;
    }
```

/ Code for reading Assignments

```
public static List<Assignment> GetAssignment()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        StreamReader textIn =
            new StreamReader(
                new FileStream(path3, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

        List<Assignment> assignments = new List<Assignment>();

        while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string row = textIn.ReadLine();
            string[] columns = row.Split('|');
            Assignment assignment = new Assignment();
            //Employee employee = new Employee();
            //assignment.Employee = columns[0];
            assignment.Employee.Name = columns[0];
            assignment.Employee.ID = columns[1];
            //assignment.Request = columns[1];
            assignment.Request.Name = columns[2];
            assignment.Request.ID = columns[3];
            assignment.Request.Desc = columns[4];
            assignments.Add(assignment);
        }

        textIn.Close();

        return assignments;
    }
}
```

// Code that reads from the textfile when the form loads

```
 private void ManagerStart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myAssignments.Employees = FileIO.GetEmployees();
        myRequest.Requests = FileIO.GetRequest();
        myAssignments.Assignments = FileIO.GetAssignment();
        lstEmployee.Items.Clear();
        lstServiceRequest.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Employee employee in myAssignments.Employees)
        {
            lstEmployee.Items.Add(employee.ToString());
        }

        foreach (ServiceRequest serviceRequest in myRequest.Requests)
        {
            lstServiceRequest.Items.Add(serviceRequest.ToString());
        }

        foreach (Assignment assignment in myAssignments.Assignments)
        {
            lstAssignments.Items.Add(assignment.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Curious: If you want to read all lines anyway, why not use File.ReadAllLines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create instances of `Employee` and `Request` that belong to `Assignment` - either in `Assignment` constructor or outside.

```
public class Assignment
{
  public Employee Employee { get; set; }
  public Request Request { get; set; }
  public Assignment()
  {
    Employee = new Employee();
    Request = new Request();
  }
}
```

or

```
Assignment assignment = new Assignment() {
  Employee = new Employee(),
  Request = new Request()
};
```

Comment: That took care of the original error I was getting but now I'm getting an Index was outside the bounds of the array at  'assignment.Request.Name = columns[2];' Any ideas?

Comment: Obviously, you have less than three items in `columns`. Show the `row` before `Split` call.

Comment: @Alex - my comment does not have any hidden meaning. Please, show us the value of variable `row` after it is assigned on the line `string row = textIn.ReadLine();` - just before "index out of bounds" exception is thrown.

Comment: "Name: Alex \t ID: 12345|Name: Chris \t ID: 5555 \t Desc: Its broken" is the value of row. Where Alex/12345 are the info for employe and chris/5555/its broken are for the service request.

Comment: @Alex - what do you expect to find in `column[2]` after splitting this line? It only has one pipe (`|`) - `column` array will have only two elements -  `column[0]` and `column[1]`.

Comment: Nevermind. I got rid of columns 2,3,4 and it is working as intended. Its just confusing because i have assignment.Employee.Name = columns[0]  assignment.Employee.ID = columns[1];   But for column[0] it is showing all info for employee and for column[1] it is showing all info for service request